# Raspberry PI : Now hold down button "KEY_OK". Something went wrong: Cannot decode data Please try again. (28 retries left)

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, lirc

I have installed and configured LIRC from https://gist.github.com/prasanthj/c15a5298eb682bde34961c322c95378b. I now try to record IR signal, but I get this error:

```
>>pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo irrecord -d /dev/lirc0 ~/lircd.conf
```

> Running as regular user pi Using driver default on device /dev/lirc0
>
> irrecord -  application for recording IR-codes for usage with lirc Copyright (C) 1998,1999 Christoph Bartelmus(lirc@bartelmus.de)
>
> This program will record the signals from your remote control and create a config file for lircd.
>
> A proper config file for lircd is maybe the most vital part of this package, so you should invest some time to create a working config file. Although I put a good deal of effort in this program it is often not possible to automatically recognize all features of a remote control. Often short-comings of the receiver hardware make it nearly impossible. If you have problems to create a config file READ THE DOCUMENTATION at https://sf.net/p/lirc-remotes/wiki
>
> If there already is a remote control of the same brand available at http://sf.net/p/lirc-remotes you might want to try using such a remote as a template. The config files already contains all parameters of the protocol used by remotes of a certain brand and knowing these parameters makes the job of this program much easier. There are also template files for the most common protocols available. Templates can be downloaded using irdb-get(1). You use a template file by providing the path of the file as a command line parameter.
>
> Please take the time to finish the file as described in https://sourceforge.net/p/lirc-remotes/wiki/Checklist/ an send it to  <lirc@bartelmus.de> so it can be made available to others.
>
> Press RETURN to continue.
>
> Checking for ambient light  creating too much disturbances. Please don't press any buttons, just wait a few seconds...
>
> No significant noise (received 0 bytes)
>
> Enter name of remote (only ascii, no spaces) :

```
conf
```

> Using conf.lircd.conf as output filename
>
> Signals are pulse encoded. Signal length is 16 Unknown encoding
>
> Please enter the name for the next button (press <ENTER> to finish recording)

```
KEY_OK
```

> Now hold down button "KEY_OK". Something went wrong: Cannot decode data Please try again. (28 retries left)
>
> Now hold down button "KEY_OK". Something went wrong: Cannot decode data Please try again. (27 retries left)
>
> Now hold down button "KEY_OK". Something went wrong: Cannot decode data Please try again. (26 retries left)
>
> Now hold down button "KEY_OK". Something went wrong: Cannot decode data Please try again. (25 retries left)

```
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

This error often comes from using FC-51 module , because this module is an infrared transmitter and receiver at the same time , for using LIRC library you must use infrared receiver module and configure the LIRC library with the out PIN of this module.